# how to return data from thread and pass into another thread python?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

i have two threads and the string parameter is constantly updating .
Problem -

a) how to pass return data from a thread

b) as string is constantly updating i heard that thread in while loop is no good  .
 how can i achieve that ?

```
Thread(target = Camera,args=(string,)).start()

Thread(target = Sound,args=(string,)).start()
```

Please help !

Comment: Strings in Python are immutable. How can you change them? Are you changing them with C code?

Comment: You are looking at a *producer* and *consumer* thread, I believe.

Comment: @PaulDraper i didn't get you !

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini i mean to say that i want to communicate message between two threads and that message is constantly changing

Comment: You can use queues: https://docs.python.org/dev/library/queue.html